# Does a report's maximum row count affect the style of pagination in Oracle Application Express (APEX) 3.1?

Tags: oracle, pagination, report, oracle-apex

I am trying to make a report use a drop-down list (select list) for pagination on a report however I have found that if the **maximum row count** for the report is set to a value above 8000 that APEX will use a pagination style of **next** and **previous** links instead. Is this a known bug of Oracle APEX 3.1?

EDIT: Pagination works as expected when the maximum row count is set to a value below 8000.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the rows per page? Maybe the select list would have had too many entries

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, Jeff! It helped me find the solution to my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the problem was that the number of rows for each page in the report was statically assigned in a named list of value (VALUE) and tied to the page item.

I then removed that item reference and the select list was used for the pagination scheme!

*I have pictures of the pagination scheme settings but my reputation is still too low to post them.*